# How do I exit a script in a conditional statement?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, scripting

I'm writing a bash script where I want to exit if the user is not root.  The conditional works fine, but the script does not exit.

```
[[ `id -u` == 0 ]] || (echo "Must be root to run script"; exit)
```

I've tried using `&&` instead of `;` but neither work.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You could do that this way:

```
[[ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]] || { echo >&2 "Must be root to run script"; exit 1; }
```

("ordinary" conditional expression with an arithmetic binary operator in the first statement), or:

```
(( $(id -u) == 0 )) || { echo >&2 "Must be root to run script"; exit 1; }
```

(arithmetic evaluation for the first test).

Notice the change `()` -> `{}` - the curly brackets do **not** spawn a subshell. (Search `man bash` for "subshell".)

Comment: Please exit with a code other than zero, example: `exit 1` in order to make understand the parent process that a problem occured.

Comment: You shouldn't use `[[` for numeric comparison, use `((`.

Comment: @ChrisDown `[[` is fine, as long as you use `-eq` instead of `==`.

Comment: Fixed the conditional, added the arithmetic version, @ChrisDown.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be It's the wrong tool for the job. Even `ksh` deprecated it (and will output a warning).

Comment: @Mat By the way, you can shorten it to `(( EUID )) && ...`

Answer (score 27):

The parentheses around those commands creates a [subshell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html). Your subshell echos "Must be root to run script" and then you tell the *subshell* to exit (although it would've already, since there were no more commands). The easiest way to fix it is probably to just use an `if`:

```
if [[ `id -u` != 0 ]]; then
    echo "Must be root to run script"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: So there is no way to do this with a one-liner?

Comment: @GarrettHall Why a one-liner? In any case you can write the if on one line: `if [[ $(id) == 0 ]] ;  then echo "Must be root to run script" ; exit; fi`

Comment: your logic is backwards.  in your example, if `id -u == 0`, which would mean that you **are** root.  You want `[[ $(id -u) != 0 ]]; then`.

Comment: @TimKennedy Gah, yes. Fixed

Comment: @GarrettHall this is identical to the one liner that is in the previous answer.  The only different between a one-liner, and a multi-line answer, is formatting.

Comment: If you /must/ have a one-liner, try this on for size: `[ "$UID" != 0 ] && echo 'You have to be root.' && exit 1;` Also note the `$UID`, which saves spawning a process. I think you might even prefer `$EUID`.

Comment: @janmoesen, good point. And while wee have a variable with a numeric value: `((UID)) && echo 'You have to be root.' && exit 1`.

Comment: Ah, yes — good catch.

Comment: @janmoesen: note that using such inverse logic will cause a script that `set -e` to abort. One solution to that problem is `[ "$UID" != 0 ] && echo 'You have to be root.' && exit 1 || true`.

Answer (score 3):

With **bash**:

```
[ $UID -ne 0 ] && echo "Must be root to run script" && exit 1
```

Comment: That would fail to exit if `echo` fails (for instance because stdout is not writable).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas wouldn't that also result in a non-0 exit tho?

Comment: @NSjonas, `echo`  (contrary to `eval`, `exec`, `:`...) is not a *special* builtin (it doesn't even have to be a builtin), so its failure wouldn't cause the shell to exit. Try `bash -c 'echo >&-; echo "$?"'`. `bash`'s special builtin only cause the shell to exit when it's in POSIX compliant mode.

Comment: your response makes me realize how little bash I actually know :0

Answer (score 1):

Brackets around `||` and `&&` are not required as these are right-associative. The following two expressions are equivalent:

```
expr1 || expr2 && expr3
expr1 || { expr2 && expr3 }
```

So `&&` instead of `;` would work just fine, as `echo` will return true.

```
[[ $(id -u) == 0 ]] || echo "Must be root to run script" && exit 1
```

Comment: While everything you said is correct, this is a bad pattern to learn, because you're relying on the return value of expr2. Are you certain that echo will always return a 0 exit status? It's much better idea to group the statements with curly braces and semi-colons. This is such a common pitfall that it has its own entry in BashPitfalls: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3

Comment: @Flimm: I don't agree it's a bad pattern. Evidently, it use is case-dependant, and also depends on your knowledge of the return values you'll get. **In this case** I'm sure echo will return 0 the 99.999% of times, and if it stomps on a write error (the only case it won't return 0) there's a bigger problem than this expr. There's also the case where YOU are generating the return values, so no, it isn't a "bad pattern" per se for me.

Comment: I'll add too, like it says in the wiki, that you should use it if sure to understand C evaluation. Anyway, a little testing should clear any ambiguities.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you , in bash

```
[oracle@rac1 ~]$ which bash
/bin/bash
[oracle@rac1 ~]$ cat test1.sh
if [ `id -u` != 0 ]
then
echo "Must be root to run the script
 "
exit
fi
```

Comment: This has already been answered and accepted. Also, your answer is near identical to what has already been posted.

Comment: @maulinglawns, that answer, contrary to the other ones has the merit of being portable to all Bourne-like shells (it would be better if the error was output on stderr, the exit status was non-zero and the command substitution was quoted though)